# Python - default arguments in function

Tags: python, urllib2

Looking at the python doc http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])

So, I pass in a url, then optional data and timeout variables (from how I read it).

So if I want to pass a timeout, but not the data... whats the default variable for data? Do you just do,

```
urlopen('http://www.example.com/', , 5)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Are we not reading the same docs? :`data` may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server, or `None` if no such data is needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the parameter names:

```
urlopen('http://www.exmaple.com/', timeout=5)
```

Comment: excellent, thank you. makes it very readable with named params

Answer (score 1):

```
urlopen('http://www.example.com/',timeout=5)
```